# Update android SDK Tools - android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

I am updating `Android SDK Tools` :

[image]

but get me bellow error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\asheq\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation02\sdk-tools-windows-3859397.zip (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.saveToFile(HttpRequests.java:339)
    at com.intellij.util.io.RequestBuilder.lambda$saveToFile$1(RequestBuilder.java:64)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.doProcess(HttpRequests.java:389)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.process(HttpRequests.java:383)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$100(HttpRequests.java:56)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestBuilderImpl.connect(HttpRequests.java:244)
    at com.intellij.util.io.RequestBuilder.saveToFile(RequestBuilder.java:64)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.StudioDownloader.downloadFully(StudioDownloader.java:86)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.BasicInstaller.doPrepare(BasicInstaller.java:71)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.prepare(AbstractPackageOperation.java:243)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.preparePackages(InstallTask.java:191)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.run(InstallTask.java:98)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:635)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$3.run(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:494)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:443)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:155)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:128)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-05-01 10:06:14,208 [  66494]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.0.1)" failed. 
2017-05-01 10:06:14,208 [  66494]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 26.0.0)". 
2017-05-01 10:06:14,259 [  66545]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-3833124.zip 
2017-05-01 10:06:14,261 [  66547]   WARN - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: C:\Users\asheq\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation03\emulator-windows-3833124.zip (The system cannot find the path specified). 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\asheq\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation03\emulator-windows-3833124.zip (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestImpl.saveToFile(HttpRequests.java:339)
    at com.intellij.util.io.RequestBuilder.lambda$saveToFile$1(RequestBuilder.java:64)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.doProcess(HttpRequests.java:389)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.process(HttpRequests.java:383)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests.access$100(HttpRequests.java:56)
    at com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$RequestBuilderImpl.connect(HttpRequests.java:244)
    at com.intellij.util.io.RequestBuilder.saveToFile(RequestBuilder.java:64)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.StudioDownloader.downloadFully(StudioDownloader.java:86)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.BasicInstaller.doPrepare(BasicInstaller.java:71)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.prepare(AbstractPackageOperation.java:243)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.preparePackages(InstallTask.java:191)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.run(InstallTask.java:98)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:635)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$3.run(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:494)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:443)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:155)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:128)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-05-01 10:06:14,264 [  66550]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - "Install Android Emulator (revision: 26.0.0)" failed. 
2017-05-01 10:06:14,266 [  66552]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Failed packages: 
2017-05-01 10:06:14,266 [  66552]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - - Android SDK Tools (tools) 
2017-05-01 10:06:14,266 [  66552]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - - Android Emulator (emulator)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Restart your **Android studio** go to `file->Invalidate Caches/Restart`

Answer (score 0):

Simply **Run Your Android Studio as Administrator** and then attempt to make the update again